# FMDatabaseQueue crash

Tags: ios, fmdb

I'm using FMDB in my app. I'm seeing this random crash happening during the app launch.

```
-(void) addActivities{
[[[DB sharedManager]getSecureQueue] inTransaction:^(FMDatabase * _Nonnull db, BOOL * _Nonnull rollback) {

        //process data
 }];
}
```

getSecureQueue returns a FMDatabaseQueue:

```
_secureQueue= [FMDatabaseQueue databaseQueueWithPath:dbPath];
```

I checked that _SecureQueue is not nil.

The crash log:

```
Crashed: fmdb.<FMDatabaseQueue: 0x170242610>
0  libdispatch.dylib              0x18ad83634 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 560
1  FMDB                           0x101040bd8 -[FMDatabaseQueue beginTransaction:withBlock:] (FMDatabaseQueue.m:228)
2  FMDB                           0x101040bd8 -[FMDatabaseQueue beginTransaction:withBlock:] (FMDatabaseQueue.m:228)
3  iPhoneHandheldACT              0x1001e4870 -[HHCTabBarController addActivities] (HHCTabBarController.m:145)
4  iPhoneHandheldACT              0x1001e553c __49-[HHCTabBarController migrateIntoRealm]_block_invoke (HHCTabBarController.m:226)
5  FMDB                           0x101040ac4 __30-[FMDatabaseQueue inDatabase:]_block_invoke (FMDatabaseQueue.m:188)
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x18ad729a0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x18ad7fee0 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 84
8  FMDB                           0x101040a34 -[FMDatabaseQueue inDatabase:] (FMDatabaseQueue.m:202)
9  iPhoneHandheldACT              0x1001e4ce8 -[HHCTabBarController migrateIntoRealm] (HHCTabBarController.m:181)
10 iPhoneHandheldACT              0x1001e4270 -[HHCTabBarController viewDidLoad] (HHCTabBarController.m:77)
11 UIKit                          0x191fecb04 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1036
12 UIKit                          0x192004590 -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 132
13 UIKit                          0x192188e18 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1144
14 UIKit                          0x1920a37bc -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 676
15 UIKit                          0x1920a3424 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 64
16 UIKit                          0x1920a3388 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 188
17 UIKit                          0x191fe9cc0 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1200
18 QuartzCore                     0x18f1da274 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
19 QuartzCore                     0x18f1cede8 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292
20 QuartzCore                     0x18f1ceca8 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
21 QuartzCore                     0x18f14a34c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252
22 QuartzCore                     0x18f1713ac CA::Transaction::commit() + 504
23 QuartzCore                     0x18f171e78 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 120
24 CoreFoundation                 0x18be689a8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
25 CoreFoundation                 0x18be66630 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
26 CoreFoundation                 0x18bd96dc4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 456
27 UIFoundation                   0x191f95134 -[NSHTMLReader _loadUsingWebKit] + 1764
28 Foundation                     0x18c9af50c __NSThreadPerformPerform + 340
29 CoreFoundation                 0x18be6942c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
30 CoreFoundation                 0x18be68d9c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
31 CoreFoundation                 0x18be669a8 __CFRunLoopRun + 744
32 CoreFoundation                 0x18bd96da4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
33 GraphicsServices               0x18d801074 GSEventRunModal + 100
34 UIKit                          0x192051c9c UIApplicationMain + 208
35 iPhoneHandheldACT              0x1000a7bf4 main (main.m:16)
36 libdyld.dylib                  0x18ada559c start + 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 8, it looks like you're already inside an `inDatabase` call (i.e. you're already in `FMDatabaseQueue` when you try to enter the queue again). Don't try to enter serial queue when you're already inside that serial queue. At best, you'll deadlock. If you do that at the wrong time (e.g. during app startup), the watchdog process will kill your app with exception code 0x8badf00d ("ate bad food"; lol; see [Technical Note TN2151: Understanding and Analyzing Application Crash Reports](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html)).

Comment: yes you are right.  I'm calling another method which starts another inDatabase call from the method which is already inDatabase! Thanks for quick response!